# How to make Build Deployment Packages for different Areas in Asp.Net MVC 4 Application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Asp.Net MVC Application I have 2 Areas.

Area 1 - CRM

Area 2 - HRM.

I have a scenario where client wants only CRM. My question is how to make Build Package of the application excluding HRM?

Can we able to do it like this?

Comment: will it not be a problem if there are some links on the root controller for the removed/ignored area?

Comment: tricky question, mean while take a look into this: http://blog.gauffin.org/2012/05/griffin-mvccontrib-the-plugin-system/?goback=%2Egmr_1931721%2Egde_1931721_member_112780884

Answer (score 0):

you should use configuration manager in your application, take a look at this:
http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/ASPNET-MVC-e28093-how-we-do-configuration.aspx